# SwiftUI List/Form bad animation when adding/removing rows

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-form

I have a really simple list with text that when the user taps on it, it expands with a datepicker inside.

The problem is that the animation looks really broken, not sure what I can do about this besides doing the entire thing from scratch, that at this point I'd rather just use UIKit.

[image]

If you have an idea of how this can be fixed I'd really appreciate.

Here's the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items = ["123", "345", "678"]
    @State private var selectedItems = Set<String>()
    @State private var test = Date()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach(items.indices) { index in
                Button(action: {
                    withAnimation {
                        if selectedItems.contains(items[index]) {
                            selectedItems.remove(items[index])
                        } else {
                            selectedItems.insert(items[index])
                        }
                    }
                }, label: {
                    Text(items[index])
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                })
                if selectedItems.contains(items[index]) {
                    DatePicker(selection: $test, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                            }
                    .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/62650979/12299030?

Answer (score 3):

`ForEach(content:)` should only be used for *static* collections.

If you have a *dynamic* collection (such as in your example - you're adding/removing entries), you need to use `ForEach(id:content:)`:

```
ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
```

---

Note that if your collection can have duplicate items, then `id: \.self` will not work properly and you may need to create a struct conforming to `Identifiable` instead.

Comment: Changing to `ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in` made no difference on the animation glitch =/

Answer (score 0):

Use `Section` inside `ForEach`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let items = ["123", "345", "678"]
    @State private var selectedItems = Set<String>()
    @State private var test = Date()

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            ForEach(items.indices) { index in
                Section(header: header(index), content: {
                    if selectedItems.contains(items[index]) {
                        DatePicker(selection: $test, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date) {
                                }
                        .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func header(_ index: Int) -> some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation {
                if selectedItems.contains(items[index]) {
                    selectedItems.remove(items[index])
                } else {
                    selectedItems.insert(items[index])
                }
            }
        }, label: {
            Text(items[index])
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
        })
    }
}
```