# Problem modifying `DatePicker` animation with `.transition` modifier

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

Adding `.transition` modifier to a conditionally displayed `DatePicker` doesn't work. It's animated with a default fade transition. Applying the same modifier to also conditionally displayed `Text` however, works as expected. What am i missing?

```
struct AddScheduleForm: View {
  @State private var startDate: Date = Date.now
  @State private var hasEndDate: Bool = false
  @State private var showEndDate: Bool = false
  @State private var endDate: Date = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent.date(byAdding: .weekOfYear, value: 1, to: Date.now)!

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      Form {
        Section {
          DatePicker("Start date", selection: $startDate, displayedComponents: [.date])
          Toggle(isOn: Binding(get: {
            hasEndDate
          }, set: { value in
            hasEndDate = value
            showEndDate = value
          })) {
            Button {
              if hasEndDate {
                showEndDate.toggle()
              }
            } label: {
              VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                Text("End date")
                  .foregroundColor(.primary)
                if hasEndDate {
                  Text("\(endDate.formatted(.dateTime.year().month(.wide).day()))")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
//                  .transition(.slide) // this works 
                }
              }
            }
            .disabled(!hasEndDate)
          }

          
          if showEndDate {
            DatePicker("", selection: $endDate,
                       in: startDate...Date.distantFuture,
                       displayedComponents: [.date])
            .datePickerStyle(.graphical)
            .listRowInsets(.init(top: 0, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8))
            .transition(.slide) // this doesn't work
          }
        }
      }
      .animation(.default, value: hasEndDate)
      .animation(.default, value: showEndDate)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably because it's inside a ```Form```. See [Not possible to control animations in a Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59009240/20386264)