# Animation when toggle switchs

Tags: swiftui

When I turn on the "Any special requests?" toggle, how can I animate other two toggles like in the video? They are sliding down from the top. My animation which is in white appearance gif but I want to make it like in black appearance gif.

[image: Animation]
**Sorry for the delay...**
[image: Animation]

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var order = Order()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker("Select your cake type", selection: $order.type) {
                        ForEach(Order.types.indices) {
                            Text(Order.types[$0])
                        }
                    }
                    
                    Stepper("**Number of cakes: \(order.quantity)**", value: $order.quantity, in: 3...20)
                }
                
                Section {
                    Toggle("Any special requests?", isOn: $order.specialRequestEnabled.animation())
                    
                    if order.specialRequestEnabled {
                        Toggle("Add extra frosting", isOn: $order.extraFrosting)
                            .transition(.slide)
                        Toggle("Add extra sprinkles", isOn: $order.addSprinkles)
                            .transition(.slide)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("CupcakeCorner")
        }
    }
}
```

I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: You probably won't be able to control the transition, because it's inside a ```Form```. See [Problem modifying DatePicker animation with .transition modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76847712/20386264) and [Not possible to control animations in a Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59009240/20386264) for similar cases.

Comment: @BenzyNeez thank you for answer. I updated the question. Can you help me again please

Comment: The issue is the same. You're still using a ```Form```, so you probably won't be able to control the transition. A workaround would be: don't use a ```Form```.